# JasmineRice on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, jasmine

Has anyone tried JasminRice gem with Rails 4?

I've got Ember Rails 4 app and I would like to use Jasmine Rice but I'm not sure whether it would work out well as their Github account says `Pain free coffeescript testing under Rails 3.1`

[Jasmine Rice](https://github.com/bradphelan/jasminerice)

Answer (score 3):

I would advice you to use [jasmine-gem](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine-gem), which recently gained Rails 4 support. `jasmine-gem` is developed by Pivotal, the company that develops Jasmine itself, and is actively maintained. While this gem was very basic for a long time, it has improved tremendously, especially with version 2.0.0. Spec execution in Phantomjs (in addition to the browser, which is the fastest for development) is supported, and there is full integration into the Asset Pipeline, which lets you e.g. write tests in CoffeeScript. At my student job, we are using `jasmine-gem` extensively and are very happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

In the [jasminerice](https://github.com/bradphelan/jasminerice) [installation section](https://github.com/bradphelan/jasminerice#installation) they mention that it should work on rails 4:

> This gem has been tested and run with Rails 3.1 and 3.2. It should
>   also run on Rails 4.

"Should" is not as strong of a word as I would like, but I have a ember rails 4 app and [jaminerice](https://github.com/bradphelan/jasminerice) has not given me any issues.